# Excel export does not show Persian characters correctly

Tags: mysql, excel, encoding, export, persian

During export of MySQL tables and views to Excel I have problems with Persian characters, they are messed up something like this:

```
Ù¾ÛŒØ§Ø¯Ù‡ Ø³Ø§Ø²ÛŒ Ú†Ù†Ø¯ Ù¾Ø±Ø¯Ø§Ø®ØªÛŒ Ù…Ø¨Ù„Øº Ø¯Ø±ØµØ¯ÛŒ
```

However encoding of tables and columns is UTF-8. I guess it may be because of ODBC driver, since exporting from SQL Server to Excel seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

That's Mojibake for `پیاده سازی چند پرداختی مبلغ درصدی`

This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

If you need to **fix for the data** it takes a "2-step ALTER", something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.